# How to get the token back from WebView after SSO in NativeScript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, single-sign-on

I’m writing an app with NativeScript & Angular 8. The app will work on Android & iOS.
I am considering putting Single Sign On technology into my app.

We will not be using the social methods to sign on such as Facebook, Google, etc. because we are writing an enterprise application for B2B purposes.

We will be using IdentityProvider & OpenID Connect.

I will get a URL from my backend server and display it in a local browser so the customers can decide which SSO service they want to use.

I thought about using this plugin to help with the SSO: https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/oauth2-oidc-client

I have implemented a simple page that will direct to the WebView with the login page. How do I get the SSO token back from this webview?

```
<ActionBar title="SSO Page" class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" (tap)="goBack()"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout class="page">
    <Webview 
        (loadStarted)="loadStarted($event)"
        (loadFinished)="loadFinished($event)"
        src="https://docs.nativescript.org/">
    </Webview>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getToken()` must be return the token on AuthService. You should be able to access it inside `homeRoute` call.

```
homeRoute: () => {
   console.log(this.authService.getToken());
   this.router.navigate(["/home"], { clearHistory: true });
},
```

**Note:** The plugin is not updated over a year and still using an older version of RxJS, you might need compat library if you are using newer version of Angular / RxJS.